# Discord.py - Report with confirm

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a report command and I want the user to confirm or deny first by adding a specific reaction. How can I check within my command if the user adds a reaction to `confirmmsg`. I tried with wait_for_reaction, but that did not work at all. 
`reaction = await client.wait_for_reaction('<:xcross:721746752650215484>', confirmmsg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at `wait_for` link to docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for